# Wordpress Website slow only for first click

Tags: wordpress, performance, nginx, w3-total-cache

I have done what all is possible that includes `w3tc (W3 Total Cache)`,dedicated server,varnish,nginx,google drive and few small plugins all installed at `socialcart.co.uk`

Now i have reached to a point where the website opens and when i click on first category then it takes 4 seconds and then i click on all categories and they all take similar time to open but if i reclick any of the category then it is super fast now.Why i can not have such super fast speed first time on first opening .It is the case for all links on index page which cause delay first time only. Any one who can help here to identify the issue as i am tired of it as fighting with speed for the last two months now.

Comment: you have to know what is browser cacheing ..

Comment: Sorry i am new to wordpress and still learning things and from browser caching what do you mean ,do you mean in w3tc  settings or else,if yes then please advise what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you're new to WordPress and you've installed NGinx and W3TC and you're wondering why the site is slow.....

Well, first of all, you're new to this, so you can't expect to make your site screaming fast overnight. It's gonna take a lot of experimentation before you know how to optimize your site. You're experimenting.... good. Keep it up.

There's a lot that goes into caching. You definitely want to read over WordPress's article in the codex about caching (https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/Caching).

And if you'll pardon a plug, I spoke at WordCamp Atlanta a few weeks ago. My biggest compliant was how many "Just do XYZ to accomplish blazing/epic/incredible/mind-blowing speed" type articles litter the internet... and just how completely off base they are. You need to know what problem you're trying to solve and what you can use to make it better. Apologies for the plug, but maybe this would help http://evan.is/wordcamp-atlanta-2014-making-wordpress-websites-fast/

Last, I feel I would be remiss if I did not mention that most people can't seem to configure W3TC correctly. And if you don't, your site is going to slow the heck down, fast. Try taking it out. Use WP Super Cache in its place. Or Quick Cache. Or Batcache. Or.... and see if that helps. If it does, don't stop there. Find out why. What's different about W3TC vs Batcache, for instance, or Super Cache vs W3TC. What might that tell you about the problem you're having?

Making websites fast is hard work.... people make entire careers of out this. You want to do this DIY and that's awesome. Keep it up. But do keep in mind it's hard work. You can't just install Nginx and W3TC and have it magically become fast for you. You have to diagnose your problem, specifically, and solve it. If this is a database slowness issue, for example, and you don't have an opcode cache... well, whatever problems you solved, you didn't solve your own.

So my question for you would be, what problem are you having? Why is your website slow? And does nginx and W3TC help with that problem?

If you don't know and you need help diagnosing it, check out Pingdom Tools, GT Metric, Webpagetest dot org, New Relic, Google Page Speed Insights, or any number of fantastic tools to help you find out what's wrong. But that's where you gotta start... your website is slow. Okay. But why? Start with why, then pick the right tool for the job.

Also, until you're pretty darn familiar with caching, it might be better to stay away from W3TC. I love that plugin. But it is not the first caching plugin you should ever use. You're very likely to do more harm than good.

Comment: Thanks and basically all this is installed by experts and finally they said that it is out of hands as they do not know or can not find what is wrong with it.They blame server and hosting company gives all ok with no issues at all.My Google insight is 82% but this first loading is only problem left now.I am sure if any one experienced this will come forward to reply .I will go through all you have listed and i am extremely thankful for the time you have given to solve this .I will still wait for more information which addresses the particular issue  i am facing.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the link you shared socialcart.co.uk opens a default web page only, with absolutely no content of any kind....

Comment: Yes may be change of DNS shows default page only.It should start resolving soon.

Comment: Website is now up and running and still first click is delayed and then it becomes fast .Any one who can help please.